# JMETER WebDriver - Explicit Wait Sample Code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I have found the Explicit Wait Sample Codes for JMeter WebDriver but not sure how to make it works. Can you please provide more sample code for WebElement? Is there any java library need to import? Below is my currently code for JMeter WebDriver. Many thanks.

My Codes:
`import org.openqa.selenium.*;`
`import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;`
`WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();`
`WDS.browser.get("https://uat-testing.com/");`
`sleep(10000);`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("xxxx@testing.com");`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).clear();`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("xxx@xxxx");`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//button/span")).click();`
`sleep(20000);`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[10]/li/span")).click();`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[16]/li/span")).click();`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[3]/li/span")).click();`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[5]/div/div/div")).click();`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li")).click();`
`WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("(//button[contains(@type,'button')])")).click();`
`sleep(30000);`
`WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();`

WebElement Sample Code:
`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`
`driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");`
`driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);`
`// Initialize and wait till element(link) became clickable - timeout in 10 seconds`
`WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))`
        `.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));`
`// Print the first result`
`System.out.println(firstResult.getText());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't [Selenium Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) provide an example?

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
// Initialize and wait till element(link) became clickable - timeout in 10 seconds
WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
// Print the first result
System.out.println(firstResult.getText());
```

you just need to remove the first line and replace `driver` with `WDS.browser` everywhere

Minimal example code in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) would be:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
def wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5)
wait.until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'More information')]")))
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I am not willing to fix your code because you don't even bother to properly format it so I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: You may define `var driver=WDS.browser` at the top and make the code look simpler. For example `driver.get(URL) ` instead of `WDS.browser.get(URL)`